# Does not work gravity when character touches the wall during a jump

Tags: unity-game-engine, character, 2d, game-physics, gravity

This happens only when :
On hit the wall during the jump + On press left and right arrows.

When there is no wall, gravity acts and character falls down.
However, when character hits the wall, Velocity Y becomes 0 immediately.
When left and right arrow key is up, character falls down again.

GroundCheck works well.

I've been thinking for a lot of time, but I do not know why.
I need help.

My game bug video : https://youtu.be/5omWCYm-y14

My Code :

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(GroundCheck.position, GroundCheckRadius, GroundLayer) != null;

    if (isGrounded)
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Z))
        {
            body.AddForce(Vector2.up * JumpForce);
        }
    }

    body.velocity = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * DefaultSpeed, body.velocity.y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set velocity directly, rigidbody will get a big horizontal force.

Replace

```
body.velocity = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * DefaultSpeed, body.velocity.y);
```

with

```
body.AddForce(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * DefaultSpeed * Vector2.right);
```

Comment: Yes. Wall has "Ground" layer.. but the ground check range is at the bottom of the character.  When character is jumping, IsGrounded = false.

Comment: @WhiteBear What about when the character hits a wall? is the `IsGrounded` still false?

Comment: Yes... it still false

Comment: The problem is disappeared! Thank you!! :)